# Use US(International with dead keys) in i3wm

Tags: keyboard-layout, i3-wm

I'm began to work on ubuntu (and arch) with `i3wm`, I usually use the US International layout on Windows. I set the keyboard of the default Ubuntu to US(International with dead keys) which works fine, but when I launch ubuntu under `i3WM`, the keyboard does not appear to have changed...

How can I set the keyboard to US(International with dead keys) with <kbd>Right-Alt</kbd> as deadkey ? should I modify anything in the `.xinit` ?

thanks for your help !

Answer (score 7):

```
setxkbmap -layout us -variant intl
```

Just picking up the comment by quixotic, which worked for me, and writing this up as an answer like Elder Geek suggested :)

Comment: Cool, what if I need accents in the other direction? I mean "è" instead of "é". So the Italian accents style. Which variant I should use?

Comment: Nevermind... I got it... Since all accents key are now dead keys, I can use them to decide which kind of accented vocals I want just typing proper accent key before the vocal! Cool!

Comment: Tried to set my i3 keyboard using `us-intl` since it is what shows up under `localectl list-x11-keymap-variants| grep us` . I'm glad I found this answer, using `intl` worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

It needed a reboot, probably because it is a virtual machine.

Comment: you can change keyboard layouts dynamically with the `setxkbmap` command.  `setxkbmap -layout us -variant intl` should do the trick.

Comment: @quixotic why not write that up as an answer. Currently it would be the best one here.

Comment: @ElderGeek time constraints. feel free to base your own answer on it, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to run `setxkbmap us\(intl\)`. You can search through available layouts using `man xkeyboard-config`.