# System not recognize my keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have Logitech Mx Keys keyboard, and use Portuguese Brazil language.

The keyboard layout is american and not works well.

If I run `set setxkbmap -model abnt -layout us -variant intl` the double quotes not works well, they go out like this `¨¨`.

If I run the command like this `setxkbmap -layout us` the double quotes works but if I need to accent words, not works, the accent go out without the letter like this. `s~ao`

I dont know what to do.

Comment: Try to press <Shift> + ' followed by space.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson it worked but if someone knows what to do to be more simple.

Comment: I was surprised to see that pressing <Shift> + ' twice didn't work as expected. Let's see if somebody else chimes in.

Comment: I took the GUI route and went to settings > Region & Language > Add an Input Source. There I searched for **English (US**, note, no `)`.  I found four US English variants: 1) English (US), 2) English (US, alt. intl.), 3) English (US. euro on 5), 4) English (US, intl., with dead keys). Of these items 2 and 4 may be of interest to you.

Comment: @user68186 my single or double quote are strage, they print ```¨¨```

Comment: Did you have a chance of testing `-variant altgr-intl` and the rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Check configuration

`man setxkbmap` shows that

```
   -query  With this option setxkbmap just prints the current rules, model, layout, variant, and options, then exits.
```

so you can check the configuration (and it would help if you post the output) with

```
setxkbmap -query -v 10
```

### Set configuration

**You might need `-variant intl` or `-variant altgr-intl`.**
But again, as per man page

```
   -variant name
           Specifies which variant of the keyboard layout should be used to determine the components which make up the  keyboard
           description.  The -variant option may only be used once. Multiple variants can be specified as a comma-separated list
           and will be matched with the layouts specified with -layout.
```

So for instance in my case to change the variant of the third layout from `intl` to `altgr-intl` I have to use a comma separated list

```
$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     latam,il,us,us
variant:    ,,intl,
$ setxkbmap -variant ,,altgr-intl,
```

In addition,
**you may need to use `-model pc105`.**
**I am not sure `-model abnt` is even a valid model** (where did yo get that from? I could only find a few, not necessarily reputable sources, using it).
A hint to this assertion is given by

```
$ find /usr/share/X11/xkb/ -type f -exec grep -nH --color abnt {} \;
/usr/share/X11/xkb/geometry/pc:831:xkb_geometry "abnt2" {
/usr/share/X11/xkb/geometry/pc:886:}; // End of "abnt2" geometry
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/sun_vndr/br:84:  xkb_symbols "abnt2" {
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/sun_vndr/br:85:  include "br(abnt2)"
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/br:2:xkb_symbols "abnt2" {
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/br:49:    include "br(abnt2)"
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/br:66:    include "br(abnt2)"
```

You may combine using *Settings* -> *Region & Language* -> *Input Sources* and choosing / adding an option (e.g., *English (US, intl., with dead keys)*), and then `setxkbmap -query` to see what may be the proper `model` and perhaps also `rules`.

### Notes

1. Out of curiosity, I checked what character you were getting

   ```
    $ printf ¨ | recode ..dump
    UCS2   Mne   Description

    00A8   ':    diaeresis
   ```
2. You can check available options with (also [1](https://manpages.debian.org/stable/xkb-data/xkeyboard-config.7.en.html), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43976/list-all-valid-kbd-layouts-variants-and-toggle-options-to-use-with-setxkbmap))

   ```
    man xkeyboard-config
   ```

   or to `cat` instead of paging

   ```
    man -P cat xkeyboard-config
   ```
3. Old linuxes allowed for using `~/.xinitrc` for permanent configuration (e.g. [3](https://zuttobenkyou.wordpress.com/2011/08/24/xorg-using-the-us-international-altgr-intl-variant-keyboard-layout/)), I am not sure it still works.
4. I have just asked [abnt not listed in xkeyboard-config models](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1339518/abnt-not-listed-in-xkeyboard-config-models)

### Related

1. [Keyboard is not configured for pt-BR](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088065/keyboard-is-not-configured-for-pt-br)
2. https://forum.mxlinux.org/viewtopic.php?t=45398&start=10
3. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/519711/portuguese-language-us-keyboard
4. [How to write in Brazilian Portuguese using a US keyboard?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008071/how-to-write-in-brazilian-portuguese-using-a-us-keyboard)
5. [One keyboard two languages on Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973153/one-keyboard-two-languages-on-ubuntu-17-10)
6. https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/problems-typing-portuguese-characters/10827
7. [Use US(International with dead keys) in i3wm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963659/use-usinternational-with-dead-keys-in-i3wm)
8. https://superuser.com/questions/1029357/how-to-use-altgr-intl-in-kde
9. https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man5/keyboard.5.html
10. [What file is the setxkbmap option -rules meant to take, and how can I add keyboard variants to that file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/876005/what-file-is-the-setxkbmap-option-rules-meant-to-take-and-how-can-i-add-keyboa)
11. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xorg/Keyboard_configuration#Using_X_configuration_files