# abnt not listed in xkeyboard-config models

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

There is a single "list" (in whichever storage form, even distributed across several files) of possible models that `setxbmap` understands. If the argument to `setxbmap -model` is not in that list, the command `setxbmap` would not understand it.

My guess (or expectation) is that the `man` page for `xkeyboard-config` should produce its output from the same "list" (i.e., the same sources) as used by `setxbmap`
*(at least when using a default configuration; I would understand if `man` did not know about user added configuration files)*.
That doesn't seem to be the case.
Command `man -P cat xkeyboard-config` does not list `abnt`, nor it is listed [here](https://gist.github.com/jatcwang/ae3b7019f219b8cdc6798329108c9aee), e.g.
But `setxkbmap -model abnt ...` works.
In this sense, `man xkeyboard-config` would be misleading.

**How can the "mismatch" be explained?**

An additional question appeared after tinkering.
If I execute `setxkbmap -model khassss ...` (a randomly invented model), `setxkbmap` does not complain, and even `setxkbmap -query` prints `... model:      khassss ...`.

**What would `setxkbmap` actually take for the model in this case, to define its behaviour?**

**Notes**:

1. `man -P cat xkeyboard-config` doesn't even give `abnt` or `abnt2` as a layout or variant, but I guess this is irrelevant for the question.
2. I am not sure the version I have plays any role in the mismatch referred to (I expect it doesn't)

   ```
   $ apt-cache policy xkb-data
   xkb-data:
     Installed: 2.29-2
     Candidate: 2.29-2
     Version table:
    *** 2.29-2 500
           500 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
           500 http://ar.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
           100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The default **Portuguese (Brazil)** keyboard layout is [designed with a Brazilian ABNT2 keyboard in mind](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/xkeyboard-config/-/blob/master/symbols/br). I'm thinking that, given the presence of that layout, it may not be considered necessary to specify abnt as a model.

Comment: Please see edited OP, which is much more precisely framed.
I am intrigued by how the link you provided fits in the question.
Probably because I cannot make sense of the expression "the presence of that layout".
1) Are you referring to the layout `pt`? How would a user tie `pt` with `abnt`?
2) Where is that "presence"? Is that in any list? Or in some file? If in a file, how would a user know of its (whatever object/layout "it" refers to) presence?

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio: I'm referring to the `br` layout, not the `pt` one, and it's included if you run `man xkeyboard-config`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about the first part of question 1.
Still, I am not clear about the rest, in the comment and the OP...

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio: I'm not clear about the rest either. ;) AFAIK it makes no sense to state a keyboard model which does not exist, and `abnt` does not exist as an XKB keyboard model. Running `setxkbmap br` without mentioning the model is perfectly valid.

Comment: Ok, now I see your point, and you may be right.
I took for granted that `abnt` is a valid model, given the fact that `setxkbmap -model abnt ...` works.
But later I found (and I posted it in the OP!) that such command does not throw any error even if using a non-existing `model`. So that might simply be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation to the mismatch

1. `man -P cat xkeyboard-config` does not list `abnt`, but
2. `setxkbmap -model abnt ...` works

is likely the following:

1. Model `abnt` does not exist (that is why it is not listed with command 1), and
2. `setxkbmap -model <any_model> ...` does not throw an error when using a non-existing `any_model`.

Observation 1 is supported by (this would not find related files in the user directory, but I have none)

```
$ find /usr/share/X11/xkb/ -type f -exec grep -nH --color abnt {} \;
/usr/share/X11/xkb/geometry/pc:831:xkb_geometry "abnt2" {
/usr/share/X11/xkb/geometry/pc:886:}; // End of "abnt2" geometry
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/sun_vndr/br:84:  xkb_symbols "abnt2" {
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/sun_vndr/br:85:  include "br(abnt2)"
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/br:2:xkb_symbols "abnt2" {
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/br:49:    include "br(abnt2)"
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/br:66:    include "br(abnt2)"
```

and observation 2 is detailed in the OP.

Perhaps Gunnar Hjalmarsson [referred](https://askubuntu.com/a/1339571/226614) to this, but that wasn't very clear to me.